# Why are some Gmail accounts listed as "googlemail.com"?

Tags: gmail, domain

I use a number of Gmail accounts for different purposes (eg. family, games-related, etc). All except one is listed as `gmail.com` but one is listed as `googlemail.com`.

Have tried removing and re-adding the account, specifically entering the account name with `gmail.com`. But after closing Chrome, when I come back to this page the account is again displayed as `googlemail.com`.

Why is this and can I change it? My preference would be `gmail.com` for all of them.

[image: One account displayed as googlemail]

Comment: Does this help? https://www.gmass.co/blog/domains-gmail-com-googlemail-com-and-google-com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @HazardousGlitch, I finally managed to track it down. These are the steps:

- Log into the `googlemail.com` account
- Click the `Settings` cog icon (upper right)
- Click `Accounts and Import`
- Find `Switch to gmail.com` next to `Send mail as:`
- Following the prompts and agree to change to `gmail.com`
- Log out of gmail
- From the landing page of your accounts, click `Remove an account`
- Remove the `googlemail.com` account
- Close and restart Chrome
- From the landing page of your accounts, click `Use another account`
- Enter the full name of the account, including `gmail.com`
- Enter the password

All done!

Answer (score 6):

To answer the question: **@googlemail.com** was created for Gmail users of a particular country (the United Kingdom, the Russian Federation, Poland and Germany) where "Gmail", as a trademark, was already taken by local folks, so Google was forced to use **@googlemail.com** instead.

Apart from this, there is also **@google.com** for Google employees.