# What is the difference between accounts.google.com and myaccount.google.com

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-management

(EDIT: Linked to https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/6363189?msgid=6363189)

I have my old Email address X@gmail.com

Initially I used an eight char password, but later I changed to an 11-char one.

Using the username `X` and my (new, so 11-char) password to sign into https://passwords.google.com/ I see that I have 2 google accounts listed:

[image]

Obviously the second one is **X**, the gmail account itself, and the first one is the implicitly created associated Google account that *HOLDS* it.

Both passwords are non-viewable, but I can see clearly they are (old) 8 cdots.

But the password I needed to get into this account is (new) **11** chars. 
 What on earth is going on here?

---

Years later I created a fresh Gmail email account (**Y**), which has become my ***Master*** account.

Now I log in as ***Y*** thru https://passwords.google.com/
*(this time I require 2FA using the Google authenticator app).*

[image]

Ok, **7** associated accounts this time. Let's have a look!

[image]

*(NOTE: The items behind the 4 grey boxes are temporary test accounts that are unused)*.

There are three things I don't understand here:

1. **Y** and **Y**@gmail.com are both absent. This seems incongruous. Y is not exhibiting the same behaviour as X was. X was self-referencing (albeit with mismatching password-lengths).  Y is not!
2. **X** appears in **THREE** locations now.

   - `X@gmail.com` (under `accounts.google.com`) with (old) 8-char password
   - `X` (under `accounts.google.com`) with NEW password
   - `X@gmail.com` (under `accounts.google.com` ***and*** `myaccount.google.com`) with NEW password

Could somebody explain this behaviour, and help me unpick this giant tangle?

I want to get a clean account structure.

Comment: your accounts are most likely not based on the same country... https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126265/186471

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered by Google representative.

Please follow the link at the top of the question to see the answer.

For reference,

> To summarise the Stack Exchange entry: You have multiple usernames and
>   passwords visible when you go to passwords.google.com One account has
>   both X and X@gmail.com saved The other account (Y) has everything by Y
>   saved. Is that accurate?   These are not sub-accounts, nor are they
>   "bound" in any way to your Google account.  They are just saved
>   credentials for accounts where you signed inm with Chrome set to save
>   them.   You want to know why you have both X and X@gmail.com, with
>   different passwords. The entries are created when you sign in through
>   Chrome and have it set to save passwords.  You can sign in to a Gmail
>   account using the bare username or the full email address, but the
>   saved password will only get updated when you sign in the same way. 
>   (Chrome's password manager does not know that they are usernames for
>   the same account.  For the same reason, you may have other entries for
>   the same account, if you sign in using other alternate usernames.)
>   You want to know why Y is not saving its own password. That is a
>   security feature.  Google will not save the password for the account
>   currently signed in to Chrome sync, because it will unlock all of the
>   other passwords.  This restriction did not always apply, so some older
>   accounts may have their own saved passwords.  It is also possible that
>   the password was saved when it was not the sync account, but the
>   profile was later synced to the account and kept the saved password.
>   You can, and should, delete any unneeded entries, especially if they
>   have old, invalid passwords.